# Parse JSON Google Finance in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse the following JSON data, but it seems that it just returns blank, I'm not sure if i am doing it right.

Could you please have a look!

```
$.getJSON('http://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=SHMN,^DJI,^IXIC,^BSESN,^SPX,^FTSE', function(data){
     $('#content').html(data);
 });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A4jKT/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all it won't get the data because the URL doesn't conform to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), this can be fixed by adding `&callback=?` to the end of the URL, this tells jQuery to [treat the request as JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp).

Also instead of applying the data directly to a `div` element I alerted it instead, this appears to show the data that's returned, you should therefore use the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4jKT/4/) as your new starting point.

http://jsfiddle.net/A4jKT/4/

Answer (score 0):

A working example of what is said above can be achieved by looking into console.log and my little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grimreaper01/jVWwu/). Note in my example, I used a two $.each statements, I'm not 100% sure why it worked, but it could be because it has 2 levels, a name and key. I got the idea from [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/jquery-each-examples/#.T9fvJ7VYvyA).

```
console.log(data);
```

It gives you an idea on how the data is contained. I used Google Chrome developer tools.